# Как вывести данные в 1 строку?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int r =in.nextInt();
    int b =0;
    int c =1;
    while (c<=r){
        b++;
        b++;
        c++;
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Как изменить код, чтобы данные выводились в одну строку?
Если есть ошибки в коде подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать.

Comment: А вы, пардон, интересовались, что делает код `System.out.println(b)`?

Comment: Выводит переменную b на консоль.

Comment: @Rubik, ну тогда вам должно быть известно, откуда берутся переводы строк.

Comment: Приму к сведению)

Comment: @Rubik а вот менять вопрос так, что полностью теряется его смысл (при этом делая существующие ответы - ошибочными) - не надо

Comment: Такого больше не повторится.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ваша программа должна выглядеть так:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(i % 2 == 0){
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Достаточно прочитать мануал от [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html):

- [`println`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(int)) - печатает переменную и совершает переход на новую строку
- [`print`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(int)) - просто печатает переменную и остаётся на той же строке

Поэтому сделайте, как здесь уже предложили до этого:

```
System.out.print(b + " ")
```

<sub>И не забывайте читать мануалы.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Вывод в одну строку

```
System.out.print(b + " ");
```